# Re-parenting Master-Detail relationship in managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, custom-object, salesforce-id, master-detail

I have installed a managed package in my org and unfortunately one of its master detail field(of one object created by  managed package) is not allowed for re-parenting. i.e., "Allow reparenting" checkbox is not checked. But I need to edit the master value for few records and update it with a new parent.

Is there any chance that i can achieve this?

Comment: I dont think you can do that.. before creating manage package you need to `Allow reparenting` checkbox need to check. This is the only solution i believe

Comment: No way to modify the fields properties if its managed.  You need to delete the incorrect records and create correct ones manually.  You can do a data load if there are a lot of records.

Comment: Can either @Ratan or gorav put their comment in an answer?